# Having a problem somewhere in my navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm trying to take it as mobile version, I don't see the menu by clicking on the place where I showed in the picture. Can someone please help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5i3h.png)

```
            <div class = "container">
                <div class = "navbar-header">

                    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle"    data-toggle = "collapse" 
                    data-target = "#micon">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href = ""><img class = "logo" src = "logo1.png"></a>
                </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "micon">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you include the cdn and css links in your index.html and css?

Comment: yes, i did, the latest ones